# 'gitk --all' command not being recognized in Windows 8 Powershell

Tags: windows, git, powershell

gitk is not working for me. I get the error saying "the term 'gitk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, ...."

One interesting thing I noted was that inside C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin\, there was a gitk file, but it had no extension. Most other files in that folder had a .exe extension.

I also made sure that C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin\ is specified in the PATH environment variable.

Also, I tried adding C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\cmd\ to PATH because it contains a gitk.cmd file, but that did not help either.

Edit : I was using Powershell earlier, since I have poshgit installed. I switched over to bash, and I was able to do gitk --all from there.

Comment: Can you run `C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin\gitk --all`

Comment: @TimCastelijns, I just tried. No, that did not work either.

Comment: Try renaming the file to gitk.exe (or gitk.cmd, if it's a script).

Comment: @PaulHicks, tried that, doesnt work either.

Comment: @PaulHicks, I made an update to the question. I was using Powershell earlier. However, I would like to keep using POwershell and would rather gitk --all worked from there.

Comment: Sorry I know nothing about poshgit or powershell.  I'd suggest reviewing gitk.cmd.  I'd guess that you were successfully running that, but whatever it did wasn't working.  gitk.cmd might not be compatible with powershell?

Answer (score 1):

I just got it to work after having the same problem.

At the PowerShell prompt it typed: "Bash" and hit return.
This put me into a bash shell.
Then I typed "gitk" at the Bash prompt and it worked.

So that gitk file is a UNIX shell script and requires the shell to work.

I suppose you could always have one of your Power Shell window in Bash mode and then this tool is available.